# Is there an automatic jQuery plugin updater?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, utilities, jquery-1.3

Is there some sort of utility available that will check my jQuery plugins and see if they are the latest version? I understand that there is not an easy way to check the version numbers automatically; but I wonder if anyone has taken a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always subscribe to the RSS feed or hit the main page and parse out this
   bit programmatically, using a DOM parser (or regex if you prefer pain):

```
<p class="jq-version"><strong>Current Release:</strong> v.1.3.2</p>
```

That said, I think the best solution is to manually check the site every couple of weeks or so. If you automatically update your production jQuery libraries, you will almost certainly face at least one catastrophe.

Also, you could do it with jQuery like so (provided you get jquery homepage via a proxy on your domain):

```
$('#someDiv').load('proxyOnMyDomain.php?get=www.jquery.com .jq-version');
```

Comment: Yeah you don't want automatic updates, but I think he just wants to be alerted.

Comment: Exactly, I do not want to automatically update them. I just want to be alerted. Watching RSS feeds for maybe 25 plugins would get annoying as well. 
I'll look in to the last part and see if that is feasible.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I assumed so from the tagline :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Yahoo Pipes is right for you... it could combine the 25 plugin feeds into one. If not, there are many other feed mashup services out there.

Answer (score 0):

What real-world problem are you trying to solve?

Perhaps [Google AJAX Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/) can help you in some way.